# TypeError: cv.Mat is not a constructor(React & OpenCV.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, opencv

I am trying to integrate Opencv.js to React(TypeScript).
What I did is:

Put

```
<script async src="https://docs.opencv.org/master/opencv.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to index.html.
And call it as global.
I wrote

```
declare global {
  interface Window { cv: any; }
}
window.cv = window.cv || {};
const cv = window.cv;
```

in react component which I want to use opencv.js.

Therefore, I solved the error "Cannot find name 'cv'." However, I am facing "TypeError: cv.Mat is not a constructor" when I use

```
let dst = new cv.Mat();
```

How could I correctly use opencv.js with React ?

Comment: You might be trying to access the `cv` property before the script has been loaded.  Look for other questions about how to properly load external scripts into react.

Answer (score 0):

try this and put it at the end of your code

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function (e){
    Main();
});
```

or put all your running code in this function and call it in your HTML

```
function Run() {
  cv['onRuntimeInitialized']=()=>{
    Main()
  };
}
```